# How to copy a drawn mask in Darktable?

Tags: software, darktable

How to copy a mask from one module to another and modify it on the second module without affecting the original mask in the first module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In the darkroom, go to the left panel
2. At the bottom of the panel, you have a masks management module
3. In the module, you have a list of modules using masks and then a list of masks
4. On the relevant mask, right click and select "duplicate this shape". You might also change the masks names to make them easier to distinguish
5. Retrieve the duplicate mask in your other module and edit it to fit your needs.

Comment: I'll just add that in DT 3.0.1, in order to "retrieve the duplicate mask", you need to go to the module you want to use it in, click "drawn mask", then click the "no mask used" dropdown and select the mask you want to use. (BTW, descriptive naming of masks is appropriate :) )